# Why is the speed of propagation of electrostatic force indifferent from the type of media?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, speed

Let say we have a charged sphere and a reactive material 1m away.If we introduce a media between them that attenuate the speed of the electrostatic force we should clearly see that the reacting material has a delay in its reaction.But as far as I know this is not true for electrostatic force propagation.Why is this so?

Comment: Where are these claims coming from?

Comment: There is a  contradiction. Electrostatic fields do not ever propagate and never have, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is incorrect. If there is a disturbance in an electrostatic force, that disturbance propagates the same way a wave does (a potentially very broadband wave).